# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

It's happening When running the PHPUnit test

The exception should be like this:

```
  +"exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"
  +"file": "..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your environment file to fix this problem

Previously

```
APP_URL=localhost
```

Changed it to

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```